# Concatenar pandas dataframes com diferentes nomes de colunas

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho dois pandas DataFrames que eu gostaria de combinar em um. Eles possuem o mesmo número de colunas, na mesma ordem, mas têm headers com nomes diferentes. Existe alguma abordagem para combinar eficientemente esses dataframes?

```
df1
index  Data1   Nome1
0      1-1-18  1
1      2-1-18  2

df2
index  Data2   Nome2
0      3-1-18  3
1      4-1-18  4

df_concat
index  Data   Nome
0      1-1-18  1
1      2-1-18  2
2      3-1-18  3
3      4-1-18  4
```

A única abordagem que eu encontrei até agora foi renomear os headers e depois usar o método concat:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
```

No entanto, eu gostaria de saber se existe uma abordagem mais geral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não me parece que tenha algo mais geral, mas adoraria encontrar uma resposta para tal.

Olhando o [Manual do pandas sobre `merging`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), Tanto o `concat` quanto o `append` criam uma cópia.

É possível usar o truque de

```
df1=df1.append(df2)
```

Porém ele vai criar uma copia inteira na memoria pra fazer o `append`, tal qual o `concat`.

No [SO tem uma pergunta a este respeito de copiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295630/how-do-i-concatenate-pandas-dataframes-without-copying-the-data), onde é colocado a possiblidade de usar `pd.merge(df1,  df2, copy=False)` (ou `df1.merge(df2, copy=False)`) quando `df1.dtype != df2.dtype`, porém não consegui resolver o seu sistema com o merge também.